# Token is refreshed on app startup but not being scheduled to be refreshed again

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

After logging in the `scheduleRefresh()` function is called and it will continuously refresh the token. The problem occurs when I refresh the page, or when an authenticated user tries accessing the web page again. `startupTokenRefresh` is called on startup, the token is refreshed, but the token is never scheduled to be refreshed again like its suppose to. If I refresh the page after I know the token has expired I get a `token_not_provided` error but I can see in the network console the token is being refreshed a couple of seconds after this error or the page has loaded. If I refresh again the request to my api is made fine but again the token does not refresh after its expired.

What am I doing wrong?

app.component.ts (on app start up)

```
platform.ready().then(() => {

  storage.ready().then(() => storage.get('token'))
    .then(token => {
      storage.set('token', token);
      authService.token = token;
      authService.authNotifier.next(true);
      authService.checkToken();
      authService.startupTokenRefresh();
    });

  authService.authenticationNotifier().subscribe((authed) => {
    if (authed) {
      this.rootPage = TabsPage;
    } else {
      authService.logout();
      this.rootPage = LoginPage;
    }
  });
}
```

auth.service.ts

```
jwtHelper: JwtHelper = new JwtHelper();
token;
refreshSubscription: any;
authNotifier: ReplaySubject<boolean> = new ReplaySubject<boolean>(1);

authenticationNotifier(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.authNotifier;
}

refresh(): Observable<any> {
    console.log("in refresh()");
    let URL = `${myApi}/refresh?token=${this.token}`;

    return this.authHttp.get(URL)
      .map((rsp) => {
          this.token = rsp.json().token;
          this.storage.ready().then(() => this.storage.set('token', this.token));
          this.authNotifier.next(true);
          return rsp.json().token;
        },
        err => {
          this.authNotifier.next(false);
          this.logout();
          console.log(err);
        })
      .share();
}

checkToken() {
    if (this.token === '' || this.token === null || this.token === undefined) {
      this.authNotifier.next(false);
      this.logout();
    }
}

public scheduleRefresh() {
  if (this.token === '' || this.token === null || this.token === undefined) {
    this.authNotifier.next(false);
    this.logout();
  }
  else {

    // If the user is authenticated, use the token stream provided by angular2-jwt and flatMap the token
    let source = this.authHttp.tokenStream.flatMap(
      token => {
        let jwtIat = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(this.token).iat;
        let jwtExp = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(this.token).exp;
        let iat = new Date(0);
        let exp = new Date(0);

        let delay = (exp.setUTCSeconds(jwtExp) - iat.setUTCSeconds(jwtIat));

        return Observable.interval(delay);
      });

    this.refreshSubscription = source.subscribe(() => {
      this.refresh().subscribe((res) => console.log('-> Refreshed...'), 
      (error) => console.log('Refresh error: ' + JSON.stringify(error)))
    });
  }
}

public startupTokenRefresh() {
  if (this.token === '' || this.token === null || this.token === undefined) {
    this.authNotifier.next(false);
    this.logout();
  }
  else {
      // Get the expiry time to generate a delay in milliseconds
      let now: number = new Date().valueOf() / 1000;
      let jwtExp: number = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(this.token).exp;
      let iat: number = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(this.token).iat;

      let refreshTokenThreshold = 10; //seconds

      let delay: number = jwtExp - now;
      let totalLife: number = (jwtExp - iat);
      (delay < refreshTokenThreshold ) ? delay = 1 : delay = delay - refreshTokenThreshold;

      // Use the delay in a timer to // run the refresh at the proper time
      return Observable.timer(delay * 1000);
      });

    // Once the delay time from above is reached, get a new JWT and schedule additional refreshes
    source.subscribe(() => {
      this.refresh().subscribe(
        (res) => {
          console.log('-> Refreshed on startup');
          this.scheduleRefresh();
        },
        (error) => console.log('-> Refresh error:' + JSON.stringify(error)))

    });
  }
}

public unscheduleRefresh() {
  console.log("unsched");
  if (this.refreshSubscription) {
    this.refreshSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

login.ts

```
onLogin() {
  this.authService.login(this.loginForm.value.username, this.loginForm.value.password)
    .subscribe(
    (response) => {
        this.storage.ready().then(() => this.storage.set('token', response.token));
        this.authService.token = response.token;
        this.authService.authNotifier.next(true);
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
        this.loginError = true;
        this.authService.authNotifier.next(false);
      },
      () => {
        console.log("login success");
        this.authService.scheduleRefresh();
        this.navCtrl.push(TabsPage);
      },
    );
    }
}
```